# Trying to define serializer using avro4s but getting a missing implicit error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro4s

I am using flink(1.7) kafka client and Avro4s(2.0.4), I want to serialize to byte array :

```
class AvroSerializationSchema[IN : SchemaFor : FromRecord: ToRecord] extends SerializationSchema[IN] {
  override def serialize(element: IN): Array[Byte] = {
    val str = AvroSchema[IN]
    val schema: Schema = new Parser().parse(str.toString)
    val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val os = AvroOutputStream.data[IN].to(out).build(schema)
    os.write(element)
    out.close()
    out.flush()
    os.flush()
    os.close()
    out.toByteArray
  }
}
```

However I am keep getting this exception :

```
Error:(15, 35) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.sksamuel.avro4s.Encoder[IN]
    val os = AvroOutputStream.data[IN].to(out).build(schema)
```

and

```
Error:(15, 35) not enough arguments for method data: (implicit evidence$3: com.sksamuel.avro4s.Encoder[IN])com.sksamuel.avro4s.AvroOutputStreamBuilder[IN].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$3.
    val os = AvroOutputStream.data[IN].to(out).build(schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to code `IN` has to be `Encoder` type:

```scala
object AvroOutputStream {

  /**
    * An [[AvroOutputStream]] that does not write the schema. Use this when
    * you want the smallest messages possible at the cost of not having the schema available
    * in the messages for downstream clients.
    */   def binary[T: Encoder] = new AvroOutputStreamBuilder[T](BinaryFormat)

  def json[T: Encoder] = new AvroOutputStreamBuilder[T](JsonFormat)

  def data[T: Encoder] = new AvroOutputStreamBuilder[T](DataFormat)
}
```

so it should something like:

```scala
class AvroSerializationSchema[IN : Encoder] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `FromRecord` when writing to the output stream. That is for people who want to have a `GenericRecord` for their own use. You need to use `Encoder`.

```
class AvroSerializationSchema[IN : SchemaFor : Encoder] extends SerializationSchema[IN] {
  override def serialize(element: IN): Array[Byte] = {
    val str = AvroSchema[IN]
    val schema: Schema = new Parser().parse(str.toString)
    val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val os = AvroOutputStream.data[IN].to(out).build(schema)
    os.write(element)
    out.close()
    out.flush()
    os.flush()
    os.close()
    out.toByteArray
  }
}
```